# Counting column contents in pandas dataframe by duplicate date

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have data like this

[image]

and I want to sum the column in `PEMAKAIAN` by same date.

I want output for example like this

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'PEMAKAIAN': [700.0, 720.0, 700.0, 700.0]})
df2 = df.groupby(['day']).sum().reset_index()
```

you will get the following df2 dataframe:

```
   day  PEMAKAIAN
0    1     1420.0
1    2     1400.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turned out that simple.